# no returns in NSJSONSerialization

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, nsjsonserialization

Could you please forgive me for eventual mistakes i can make asking this question me it's my first one here.

After reading several topics on this website, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12255290/using-nsjsonserialization-to-parse-json) first i'll try to use the describe methods but it still doesn't work @ all :-(

My .json file looks like this

```
{ "speakers" : 
  [
    {
    "name":"Value",
    "picture": "URL VALUE",
    "business":"VALUE",
    "desc":"VALUE",
    "twitter": "URL VALUE"
    }                   
    {
           ...

    }
  ]
}
```

So this is my reasoning :

I firstly have a **dictionary** which contains *speaker* attribute 
   This one contains an **array**, field by some **dictionnaries** within *"name", "business"*,... attr.
So, this is my obj-C code :

```objc
NSString *URLStr = @"URLofMyJsonFile";

NSURLRequest *JSONRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithString:URLStr ]]];

NSData *JSONData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:JSONRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil];

NSError *parsingError = nil;

NSDictionary *speakerDictionnary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSONData options:0 error:&parsingError];

NSArray *speakersArray = [speakerDictionnary objectForKey:@"news"];

for (NSDictionary *oneSpeaker in speakersArray) {
    NSLog(@"The speakers's name is %@", [oneSpeaker objectForKey:@"name"]);
    NSLog(@"The speakers's business is %@", [oneSpeaker objectForKey:@"business"]);
    NSLog(@"The speakers's desc is %@", [oneSpeaker objectForKey:@"desc"]);
}
```

EDIT : I remplace the right URL of my Script with Dummy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON isn't valid, there needs to be a comma between the individual speaker dictionaries.

```
{ "speakers" : 
  [
    {
        "name":"Value",
        "picture": "URL VALUE",
        "business":"VALUE",
        "desc":"VALUE",
        "twitter": "URL VALUE"
    } <=== MISSING COMMA HERE       
    {
       ...
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As omz mentioned the json is wrong. you can try below code :

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.appios.fr/client/takeoff/app/script/jsonSpeaker.json"]] queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *reponse,NSData *data,NSError *error){
        if (!error) {
            NSError *jsonError;
            id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&jsonError];
            NSArray *speakersList = [json objectForKey:@"speakers"];
            [speakersList enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *dict,NSUInteger idx,BOOL *Stop){
                NSLog(@"Name : %@",[dict objectForKey:@"name"]);
            }];
        }

    } ];
```